# Firebase CLI - "Invalid project ID specified"

Tags: node.js, firebase, npm

I'm trying to use `Cloud Functions` in my `Firebase` project.

I'm trying to initialize the `CLI features` in a new folder in my Mac. I opened a folder which called `CloudFunctions` and ran the `firebase init` command into this folder, and this is what happens:

[image]

It doesn't ask me if I'd like to set a new default `project ID` for this folder, but it's using an old `project ID` which is probably wrong.

---

When I try to run `firebase use <my_project_id>` I get this error:

[image]

but as you have seen above, running `firebase init` fails because the default `project ID` is wrong.

---

**The CloudFunctions folder is currently empty, it doesn't have `firebase.json` file or any other file.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Firebase CLI will look in the current directory and all of its parent directories for a .firebaserc file that describes a project.  You probably have a .firebaserc file in your home directory, which it thinks is the project that you're currently working on.  Move that file out of the way (and figure out if it's actually something you want to keep using).

Comment: This is the correct answer, but it worth mentioning that I couldn't see this file because it was hidden. After reading your answer I have enabled showing hidden files on my Mac, and only than I could edit it.

Comment: In unix type systems, all files beginning with a dot are hidden by the usual tooling.  You can also cause them to appear on the command line with `ls -a`.